# LINQ execution time

Tags: c#, linq

today I noticed that when I run several LINQ-statements on big data the time taken may vary extremely.

Suppose we have a query like this:

```
var conflicts = features.Where(/* some condition */);           
foreach (var c in conflicts) // log the conflicts
```

Where `features` is a list of objects representing rows in a table. Hence these objects are quite complex and even querying one simple property of them is a huge operation (including the actual database-query, validation, state-changes...) I suppose performing such a query takes much time. Far wrong: the first statement executes in a quite small amount of time, whereas simply looping the results takes eternally.

However, If I convert the collection retrieved by the LINQ-expression to a List using `IEnumerable#ToList()` the first statement runs **a bit slower** and looping the results is very fast. Having said this the complete duration-time of second approach is much less than when not converting to a list.

```
var conflicts = features.Where(/* some condition */).ToList();           
foreach (var c in conflicts) // log the conflicts
```

So I suppose that `var conflicts = features.Where` does not actually query but prepares the data. But I do not understand why converting to a list and afterwards looping is so much faster then. **That´s the actual question**

Has anybody an explanation for this?

Comment: LINQ queries are _lazy_. They are only evaluated when it is actually required. Such as when you call `ToList` or try to iterate through the results.

Comment: And this is the case when converting to a list, right?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, ignoring all the other folk that don't seem to have read your question, I can see no reason why calling ToList() and iterating over the list in total would be quicker than just iterating over the collection.  If anything it should be slightly (probably immeasurably so) slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement, just declare your intention:

```
var conflicts = features.Where(...);
```

to get the data that fullfils the criteria in `Where` clause. Then when you write this

```
foreach (var c in conflicts)
```

The the actual query will be executed and will start getting the results. This is called `lazy loading`. Another term we use for this is the deffered execution. We deffer the execution of the query, until we need it's data.

On the other hand, if you had done something like this:

```
var conflicts = features.Where(...).ToList();
```

an in memory collection would have been created, in which the results of the query would had been stored. In this case the query, would had been executed immediately.

Generally speaking, as you could read in wikipedia:

> Lazy loading is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming
>   to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is
>   needed. It can contribute to efficiency in the program's operation if
>   properly and appropriately used. The opposite of lazy loading is eager
>   loading.

**Update**

> And I suppose this in-memory collection is much faster then when doing
>   lazy load?

[Here](http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-3-lazy-loading) is a great article that answers your question.

Comment: Or called *delayed execution* (there is even better word instead of delayed, can't remember.. *dettered*?)

Comment: And I suppose this in-memory collection is much faster then when doing lazy load?

Comment: Lazy loading is a different thing. This is lazy evaluation (or deferred execution)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of lazy evaluation. With LINQ the query is not executed until the result is needed. Before you try to get the result (ToList() gets the result and puts it in a list) you are just creating the query. Think of it as writing code vs running the program. While this may be confusing and may cause the code to execute at unexpected times and even multiple times if you for example you foreach the query twice, this is actually a good thing. It allows you to have a piece of code that returns a query (not the result but the actual query) and have another piece of code create a new query based on the original query. For example you may add additional filters on top of the original or page it.

The performance difference you are seeing is basically the database call happening at different places in your code.